# USB Overdrive won't stay installed in Yosemite

Tags: osx-yosemite

When I install USB Overdrive, and restart my Mac, it doesn't recognize USB Overdrive, and it has to reinstall it again. I can only use it for the duration of the session I installed it in.

How can I make USB Overdrive STAY installed?

Comment: You are using the current release?

Comment: USB-Overdrive-31.dmg

Comment: Does that mean you have `USB Overdrive 3.1`?  Have you contacted the [author](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Contacts.html) for assistance?

Comment: yeah im using that one. i haven't contacted him. thanks i will.